# Is it possible to play new Skyrim DLC using an old character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to buy the game with no DLC, create a character (and play a fair bit), buy the DLC, install it, and play the newly installed DLC using the old character?

Also, I am playing on the XBox 360.

Comment: It's...Skyrim.  You only *get* one world.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the character. Think "character" instead of world, i guess.

Comment: Still, that's exactly how DLC works for most games.  You don't have to start over to use DLC.

Comment: So, to clarify, I can buy and install the DLC, but still use my main character (created before purchase of DLC) while also using the DLC? Thats great!

Comment: Yep.  Very few games are going to make you start over, for exactly this reason.

Comment: In fact, as you are installing Dawnguard, vampires will take advantage of your being out of game to sack The Hall of the Vigilants.  The sneaky buggers don't even need any CPU cycles!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that is possible. That's exactly how I (and many others) played Skyrim.

If you bought Skyrim at launch, no DLC was available. Once you have purchased it, it will integrate naturally with your ongoing character.